# A few rewrite rules, causing 404 to not work properly

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a Front controller doing the following:

```
$pages = array('home', 'login', 'create-account', 'activate');
$page = ((empty($_GET['p'])) ? 'home' : $_GET['p']);

if (in_array($page, $pages) && file_exists($page . '.php'))
    include $page . '.php';
else
    include '404.php';
```

Then I have this `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(activate)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&f=$2
```

If I visit

http://localhost/folder/login

It works:

If I visit:

http://localhost/folder/$$$$

It would give me an real 404 (not my custom :P), not sending me to the 404 page. This is because of the rewrite rule :

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L] since it only accepts a-z and -

If I rewrite it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

It would work and send to 404, but then this rewrite wouldn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(activate)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&f=$2
```

Since the first will match.

If I try to change place:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(activate)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&f=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I am getting the 404 on all pages.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Your rewrite rule seems to only be looking for lower cases letters and dashes?

Comment: Please the read the whole question.

Comment: You might want to try `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1` which will exclude any string with a / in it (and thus your first one will work again.)  But this will cause junk with /s in it to not get slurped in.

Comment: I wouldnt want any problem or junk with /s anyelse way i can solve it?

Comment: Isn't it possible to point the user to a certain url (404) unless none of the rewrites are matched

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved. With different method, I parsed the url with PHP instead.

Comment: Your rewrite rules are plain & simple wrong. You are probably able to mask the actual problem by some PHP code for now but it will eventually come back to pinch you in long run.

Comment: In that case present your full solution in your answer. Otherwise you may opt to delete your question altogether.